# Obtener nombre de archivo Codeigniter modelo MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

tengo un form en mi vista donde en un punto cargo un archivo:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">archivo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="file" name= "file" class="form-control" id="file">
</div>
</div>
```

esto lo envió  a mi controlador y de ahi guardo el archivo en un servidor ademas lo envio por correo y tambien envio los datos del form a mi modelo para almacenarlos en una base de datos donde quiero guardar el nombre del archivo pero no encuentro la propiedad para hacer este paso.

Función del modelo.

```
function ingresarRpoerte()
    { 

    $causa = array(
        'fecha_emision' => $this->input->post('fecha_ingreso'),
        'tipo_perito' => $this->input->post('tipo'),
        'mencion_perito' => $this->input->post('mencion'),
        'nombre_perito' => $this->input->post('nombre'),
        //'email_perito' =>
        'rit_perito' => $this->input->post('letra')."-".$this->input->post('numero')."-".$this->input->post('anio'),
        'caratulado_perito' =>$this->input->post('caratulado'),
        'ruc_perito' => $this->input->post('RUC'),
        //'nombre_archivo_perito' => $file_name,
        'juez_perito' => $this->input->post('juez'),
        'generado_perito' => $_SESSION['usuarios'],
        'prox_fecha' => $this->input->post('fecha_plazo'),
        'enviado_a_perito' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")

 );   
    //insertamos el array en la BD de historial
    $this->db->insert('saus_reporte_perito', $causa); 
    }
```

Comment: Te aconsejo echarle un vistazo a la librería **upload** que tiene **Codeigniter**: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Primero que nada te recomiendo declarar bien tu form con el enctype adecuado, segundo procesa los datos del form en el controller y de hay envía el arreglo al modelo para solo insertarlo en la bd.